# Get last update date and time from head request

Tags: php, datetime, http-headers, httpwebrequest

From this array I need the date and time according to GMT+1. First question is how do I get the ' date ' from the headers array. Second, how do I format it to 2011-10-09 08:40 (which is the format, and the time in GMT+1).

```
Array ( [headers] => Array ( [Date] => Sun, 09 Oct 2011 07:40:10 GMT [Server] => Apache [Last-Modified] => Sun, 09 Oct 2011 07:39:29 GMT [ETag] => "10c8000a" [Accept-Ranges] => bytes [Content-Length] => 198311 [Content-Type] => image/jpeg ) [info] => Array ( [url] => http://domain.no/webcamera/broadcast.jpg [content_type] => image/jpeg [http_code] => 200 [header_size] => 208 [request_size] => 214 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.208861 [namelookup_time] => 0.003067 [connect_time] => 0.025592 [pretransfer_time] => 0.0256 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 198311 [speed_download] => 949487 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => 198311 [upload_content_length] => 0 [starttransfer_time] => 0.049787 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) ) [curl_handle] => Resource id #2 )
```

Answer (score 1):

First, to get the date you would have do do something like this:

> *I assume the array is the variable $pie*

```
$pie['headers']['Date']
```

To create a datetime object, see [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). And to format the date, [see](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-format.php).